# How to retrieve the url and its params the controller is posting to in rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In our rails 3.2 app, the action `search_results` is responding to a search form submitted by a user. Here is the full URL shown in browser for action `search_results`:

```
http://localhost:3000/engine_configs/search_results?utf8=%E2%9C%93&engine_config[start_date_s]=&engine_config[end_date_s]=&engine_config[engine_id_s]=1&engine_config[argument_name_s]=&engine_config[commissioned_s]=&commit=%E6%90%9C%E7%B4%A2
```

In rails controller, the url and its GET params are stored in `url`_for and `request.GET` respectively:

```
url_for = "http://localhost:3000/onboard_data_upload/engine_configs/search_results"
request.GET = ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess (3 element(s)) #(utf8, params[:engine_config] & commit)
```

Is there a rails built-in method retrieving the full url (url shown above in browser) for the action `search_results`? Or if there isn't, what's the right way to assemble the full url?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you storing the full URL? I can't think of an instance where this would be required.

Comment: For 'Back' button to know what's the previous URL to render. We have custom Back button which always falls back to the previous page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your routes.rb file, add `, as: :search_results` to the end of the route. Then you can use `search_results_url` and `search_results_path` in your controllers and views.

PS: The older Ruby hash syntax `, :as => :search_reults` would work as well.

Comment: Is it the same as what url_for returns? We need both the path and the params to returned in url.